# jQueryUI draggable to sortable "over" event not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, events, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

Here's my story - I have a draggable list of items that is connected to sortable list via

```
connectToSortable   : ".cell-wrapper",
```

Problem is, jQuery UI doesn't fire "over" event when draggable is over sortable. It does create a placeholder in cell, though. Is there a way I can run my code when my draggable item is over the sortable item? Thanks.